# Custom Android application launcher

Tags: android, shell, dashboard, kiosk, launcher

I want to create an application "menu" which houses 4 or 5 icons which launch customs applications specific to my company.  Is there a specific way to do this in Android?

I don't know what it would be called, exactly, and googling "android launcher", "menu" and "application shell" just bring up a lot of unrelated static.  What's this called in android parlance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wufoo,

It sounds like you want an application dashboard.  The Google iosched example program might get you on the right path: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Unless you mean to have the device ONLY launch your applications, then your app would be a complete Launcher replacement.  The Launcher is described as...

> The activity can be the initial activity of a task and is listed in the top-level application launcher.

But that may no be what you want.

Comment: Ahhh.. yes, the dashboard.  That's the only buzzword I couldn't think of googling.  Yep, in the link you sent, I want to do something like what's in the left pic.  Having other stuff on the phone is fine, I just want a "main menu" type application window to launch stuff like a corporate contact list, home page app, etc.

Comment: next week it'll be called a cyberdash or something.  keep up! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to replace the device home screen and act as the default launcher?

If so you can use some intent filters as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android/2071230#2071230):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use home-screen folders to manage arbitrary groups of app launcher icons. Long-press on the home-screen background and select "Folder" to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Kiosk Mode. You could customise this (disable access to menu, limit application addition etc)  http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus/