# Run only one custom app in Android, prevent anything else from running

Tags: android

Is it possible to make Android be able to run only one app? It seems that making a custom ROM might be the option.Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: why would you want to do that? You could replace Home/Launcher activity with your app, though

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android

Comment: many thanks for mentioning 'kiosk mode', a search on this keyword has already given some interesting results. And yes, replacing Home/Launcher seems a good idea as well.

Comment: @DumitruHristov This SO question is the first Google hit. Could you share your experiences in an answer? Currently, there are only rough hints here and no more (recent) solutions. -- My use case is a kids phone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerous answers and questions on this already. Basically you have the following options:

1. Creating you own rom.
2. Creating your own launcher application.

The best solution is definitely 1, but it's much more complicated. Making your own launcher application could be a solution but it would never be perfect, there would always be ways for the user to get back to normal Android, so if you can't accept that then you need to make your own rom.

Comment: If you just create a launcher app the user will have the option of selecting which launcher to use, so they can switch back to the system launcher. The only option to really lock down is to have a custom rom with the original launcher removed. If your device is supported well by Cyanogen you may want to start there :)