# Blocking websites on Android

Tags: android

Is there any way of blocking websites programmatically on an Android device? I would like to have a blacklist of URLs that are populated into a continually running service. When the user running under restricted terms opens a browser, it should check that blacklist.

I've thought of modifying the hosts.allow and hosts.deny files, but those are protected.

Comment: @cularis: OP is asking `programmatically`..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is possible on a rooted device - there are some free firewalls. But on a regular device this might not be possible.. I think it would require  [Kiosk mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)

Comment: There is a trick, I also searching that, Some of the apps are doing this with out root permission. Like kasperacy app.

Comment: Those apps get the authorization of being device administrators may be that might be the reason for their ability