# restrict url access used by third party library within mobile app

Tags: android, url, android-manifest

I have a unique situation while developing my andorid mobile app. I am using some third party libary to get the bluetooth reading within my application. so far i am able to get the 
reading successfully but when the third party libary takes the reading from bluetooth device and it sends the reading to its own server, after that it passes the reading to my application.

so i want to restric the call made by third party libary , following is the ulr that the libary is using.

> https://mobile.XXXX.com/v1/organizations/

is there any way to block the above url by programmaticallyor by declaring some setting in android `manifest` file

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar article over [here](https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/block-specific-url-access-and-how-create-url-whitelist)

It shows how to block specific URL access and How to create a URL whitelist

I don't have much knowledge of blocking URL's I simply use match cases for a specific website name for example

```
   if(websiteName.equals("WEBSITE_TO_BLOCK.com")){
        //Do nothing }
```

Comment: not a relevant solution at all , the article that you are referring to is `Knox Standard SDK` and not android native. Moreover the code that you have shared is not helpful

Comment: @Hunt oh sorry for that as I said I have no experience with Android Network Blocking functionality, I have read several similar questions over stack overflow one of similar question is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839841/blocking-websites-on-android), I think blocking is not allowed on non-rooted devices