# How to disable status bar / notification bar on android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-manifest

i create a lockscreen application.. this application is triggered by SMS.. when a SMS containing command was received, it will display a lock screen activity.

my lockscreen activity is using TYPE_KEYGUARD for disabling a home screen button. When device screen turn off and then i turn it on again, my problem is status bar /  notification bar still appear on my screen. this is a problem because the user still can access some program through status bar / notification bar even the device is being locked. so i want to dissapear this status bar / notification bar so that the user (theft) can't access that device anymore..
Please help me to solve this..

Comment: means you want to disable status bar/notificatio bar from activity startup?

Comment: did you find a solution to that? I m still struggling with that same issue. thx

Comment: Only working solution fond for KitKat:
[Click Here for Answered][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371802/permanently-hide-android-status-bar/26645768#26645768

Answer (score 12):

I think what you're trying to do is programmatically set an activity as fullscreen. If so, consider the following:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Source: http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-make-an-activity-fullscreen

Answer (score 6):

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

only disables the activity's title bar, not the notification bar at the top.

Use this theme in android manifest for your activity :

```
"Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

did work for me.

It hides the notification bar.

Answer (score 4):

### On Android 4.0 and lower

Option 1:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

Option 2:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
        // the status bar.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    ...
}
```

### on Android 4.1 and Higher

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

> And for Android 4.6(Api 19) and higher use the [Immersive Full-Screen
>   Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

[Reference from Google](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#41)