# How to DISABLE status bar in Android?

Tags: java, android, hide, statusbar

I want to disable status bar in my application.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578804/how-to-disable-status-bar-notification-bar-on-android-programmatically)

with:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I still can activate status bar with fast swipe from top to bottom screen.
Is possible to fully deactivate it?

Answer (score -1):

What API version are you using? Anyway in the dedicated android developers page ([Hiding the Status Bar](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)) there is a detailed explanation on how to do it with additional clarification for API<16. In particular *if the status bar should always remain hidden in your app* you should set the activity theme in your app's manifest file as follows:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: I can still enable status bar by swiping up to down. It will disappear in seconds but I want to completely disable it. Im working on api 16 SGS II.