# Disable status and naviagation bars

Tags: android, android-view

Problem - I try to disable status and navigation bar when active my app (Android 7+)

I found few solution :

```
theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

and

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
);
```

This solutions hide bars, but if do swipe down/up - bar showned.

I saw application that turned off these bars, how is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Hide & Disable Notification (Status) Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581565/android-hide-disable-notification-status-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to disable the ability to swipe the bars back in.  As a normal app, you are not allowed to take over the device and prevent the user from exiting the app.

If you're trying to develop a "kiosk mode"-type app, take a look at the [APIs for dedicated devices](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices).