# Web Block for Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-intent, android-browser, parental-control

I am making a parental control, does anyone know how to prevent a It from opening a site. I get to know when a URL is entered in the browser using content providers. I try to redirect it, works but when the browser is closed and then started again it goes to the blocked site as it does not make any changes in the table my receiver is not called. I have tried deleting all records from the browser table but it does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android