# Android 2.1 Tablet Fullscreen app

Tags: android, fullscreen, tablet, statusbar

I need to launch appliaction in fullscreen mode (or just not leavable) on Wooky Reader tablet (it is most likely the same as Archos 70b), which runs on Android 2.1.
I've made some tries that did not work:
in manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

i've add permission:

```
 uses-presmission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR
```

just for the case.
In code i tried:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And combinations of these.
I know that removing status bar is "prohibited" on tablets, but i've found some ways for Android 3.0+ versions. So is there any way to do that on this specific tablet?
I will be glad for any ideas.

EDIT: now i tried:

```
uses-permission android:name="archos.permission.FULLSCREEN.FULL"
```

-> did not work

Comment: I suppose that in android 3.x the application can't hide status's buttons.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android