# how to create android app that launch when device boot and block to go device home

Tags: android, boot

I am trying to make an android app that will show only my app and other native app will work under my app's interface.. That means when the device starts my app will load by default and user not allowed to exit from my app by pressing any key or buttons in the device.

is there any way to do this, please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You may get some ideas from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android