# Lock windows phone device to use a single application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to make an application as default instance when device is booted(eg. start-up run) and also at run time?

And more important to fully disable the access of the user to any other application on the device. The user should only see and work in my application without being able to close it.

Why I'm asking this?
- I must develop an application for my company and they asked if it's possible to make the OS to show only that single application.

Thanks,

Comment: if it could only run your app it wouldn't be much of a phone

Comment: The devices are going to be used only for this application.

Comment: however you could make the phone part of an org policy (or whatever they call it) and limit what could be installed

Comment: Shaun Wilde - That wouldn't help , it's not what I'm looking for. I've seen this guy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127947/lock-android-device-to-a-single-application . That's what I need ( look at the last answer )

Comment: I've only seen that capability (kiosk mode) in android devices and windows CE but not in modern windows phones, perhaps possible on surfaces/tablets.

Comment: looks like they call it assigned access - http://mobilitydojo.net/2014/04/14/windows-phone-8-1-kiosk-mode/ - have fun