# How to override activity's fullscreen exit gesture?

Tags: android, gestures, parental-control

Is it possible to override the swipe-down gesture used to display the notification bar and the back-home-cards control buttons in a fullscreen android activity?

I'm developing a baby-proof app and sometimes the baby would swipe down the screen and exit the app (by tapping on a notification or the home button). I would like to change the gesture from swipe-down to tapping on a certain region or triple tapping the screen for example. Is it possible?

Comment: Interesting topic! I'll be watching for interesting answers. Have you done any research so far? Your question's quality would look much better if you'd provide urls to the resources you've read. Please have a look at [ask] and consider [edit]ing your question.

Comment: @aquiros +1 for your concept

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock Android Device to a Single Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127947/lock-android-device-to-a-single-application)

Comment: [This](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) tutorial might be what you're looking.