# How to use Pepper robot app as startup default application?

Tags: javascript, pepper

I want my app to start when pepper is started and when some other app is opened and then closed (like settings) it should go back to my app.

I tried doing it in preferences but seems like i am missing something.

Does anybody got some examples?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned which operating system you wished to use, as the solution will likely be different for each. You probably want to search for [kiosk mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24127947/1270789).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the launch trigger condition in choregraphe. For example, your want to launch your main behavior when Pepper is in life mode in "solitary". For that you must open your choregraphe project and click on properties :

[image: Example in choregraphe]

After that you will have the properties of your application. For modifying the launch trigger of your application, you must click on your main behavior and change the launch trigger condition like below :

[image: Modification launch trigger condition]

With that, your application will be launched automatically when pepper will be in interactive mode of autonomous life .

Answer (score 1):

There's a far better and standard way to do that.

1. Install your behavior as startup using standard command, for instance from choregraphe: as seen for instance there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9RFkpI4vjo
2. Do your stuff at startup, keep your behavior running and register to events or signal, as ALBehaviorManager/BehaviorsAdded() or ALBehaviorManager::behaviorStarted() and ALBehaviorManager::behaviorStopped().
   You can find more info in the ALBehaviorManager documentation, for instance, there:http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/core/albehaviormanager-api.html

Comment: 1. Got it. Was able to do it. 2. Are there any examples of this usage?

Comment: Something is overrunning this. If my startup behaviour has tablet view in it then it is interrupted with something else. For example i added to startup behaviour say "Default app is started" and then it should also open the index.html view but instead i get white loading screen with black dots and then it goes to black bubble view. Is there a way to start it after the white loading screen view

Comment: You should either tell the autonomous life to start your program (in your behavior properties, test changing autonomous or interactive or ...) You can also manually disable the autonomous life. All depends on your usage (for scientific research or for a commercial application)

Comment: (for instance: "no nature")

Comment: Where can i change behavior properties. Do you mean manifest.xml ?

Comment: You could perhaps create another question as other people would like to know this kind of informations...

Answer (score 0):

By design, Pepper is meant to be run with "Artificial Life" on, and automatically start "the dialog". You must either uninstall the "the dialog"-app or disable autorun in its manifest.xml.
For running your application automatically: The easy solution is to copy the autorun parameters from "the dialog" manifest.xml and paste them into the manifest of your own app.