# Can I lock Android device using LibGdx

Tags: android, locking

I am writing an android application using LibGdx. 
My question is can I lock Android device.
**То be active only this app.**

Comment: Do you mean prevent the home and task manager buttons from working, and block incoming calls and the notification bar? If so, no you can't do this in any Android app.

Comment: Yes. I mean to use the device only in this one app.

Comment: perhaps kiosk mode ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Libgdx question, but an Android platform question.

"Locking" an Android device generally means using the lock screen to prevent access to the device.  What you are asking for is more of a "Kiosk" mode.  Since this feature would also enable ransomware, its generally not allowed.  More details here: [Kiosk mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your answer helped me. He gave me direction.

`<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>`

Comment: Now I have the following problem about one time selected default action "Home" button to change it programming way from app. 
If anyone has an idea?