# Android: Make app not closeable (kiosk) under certain circumstances

Tags: android, restart, kiosk

I have a problem that I don't really know how to solve and also the threads here at SO haven't fully helped me.
Here's the issue: I want to have an android app that I can start whenever I want, and then, when I click on a button, I want the app to be somewhat "locked". By that I mean: after this button was pressed, the user is not able to **close**(see edit below) the app. Also, the app should immediately start after rebooting the device.
This lock can then be revoked by, say, entering a passcode, which makes the app run normally again.

So far I understand how to build kiosk applications. However, a kiosk application needs a particular manifest which will make it always a kiosk app, and not "on demand".

I'd greatly appreciate any hints and tips on this topic. Thank you so much!

**EDIT:** by "close" I really only mean completely turning the app off, not only going back to your home screen. Such that the app is always running in the background

Comment: what do you mean with "particular manifest" ?

Comment: something like <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />

Comment: I haven't actually worked out code for this, but I suspect that you can probably make the app technically a Kiosk app all the time, but have it simply pass on to the home screen unless the variable is set. That is, have it always start, but when the button is turned "off" it just exits immediately.

Comment: you should use Screen Pinning (Android 5 feature)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Kiosk mode in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)

Comment: Lynn, I don't think it's a duplicate because I want to particularly turn the kiosk mode on and off.

Gabor, I will look into that, however I would also need support for Android 4.

jwriteclub, I will see how I could do that.

Comment: use Lollipop 5.0 screen pinniung

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically lock and unlock the App in Android 5.0 http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenPinning