# Launch activity before Home screen on boot

Tags: android, boot

I'm making an android app and my requirement is that I want to launch an activity as soon as the boot it completed, i.e. before any home screen or launcher. Using BOOT_COMPLETED with Broadcast receiver takes quite long (10-20 seconds) and I don't want that delay. I know that this intent filter for activity works well with rooted phones

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But I want to achieve this in non rooted phones as well... Is there any way for doing so??

Comment: I think you are talking of a Broadcast Receiver, which in turn launches a Service. Not an Activity.

Comment: Maybe you should *be* the home screen.  At a certain point you have to accept that *stock* Android isn't really designed for specialized uses, but rather compartmentalizes 3rd party components and limits what they can do.

Comment: 1- You will need to revise Android Boot Sequence steps. use Hardware related  Broadcast receiver. I used wifi on a Lenovo tab, I got 5sec before boot receiver. 
2- You can try adding Application class. This class starts well before Broadcast receiver. Take care for calling service early, as it will through exception.
-- using the above Methods requires testing the target device, to be sure everything is going smooth, and the time difference gained worth it (Lenovo case)
3- Being android launcher. see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android