# Restrict users access to only certain Settings like Bluetooth, and GPS

Tags: android

Working on Kiosk app and trying restrict users access to just a few setting functions.  In particular, GPS Settings.  If Setting Dialog is brought up there is a little back/home button in at top of settings that allows users to click back to access all settings. I don't want them to be able to go back and set everything.  Is there anyway to disable this or will I need to make custom interface to turn on/off each item under location services? The back button might be firing up another intent which could be caught or than again maybe its just calling finish or closing out dialog or fragment ...

Does anyone know what the little back button does under the hood? Any way to catch intent fire at this point?

Comment: Check the answer here, try to make your app full screen and restrict access to move out of your app http://stackoverflow.com/a/24540023/1150135 Also there is a new concept discussed here https://objectpartners.com/2014/11/04/building-a-kiosk-application-in-android-5-0-lollipop/

Comment: Ok, appreciate it. Thanks