# Prevent android image to install unsigned apks

Tags: android

I'm developing a system based on Android. I'm thinking about a way to prevent my system to accept unsigned apks. There is a way to do this? I have the acess to compilation environment and I can make changes on image building.

Comment: Depending on what system you want to build you may have a look at kiosk mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android

Comment: @BrunoBieri no, I need that my android environment don't accept any attempt of non signed apk installation