# How can I properly and permanently hide the status and navigation bars on Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I'm building an app for Android (6.0, but I can change it if necessary), and having trouble getting the status and navigation bars to hide properly. I've followed every online suggestion I can find, but the two bars both hide properly whenever the app is launched or resumed, but they instantly reappear whenever I tap. I've added the following code to `styles.xml`:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

And in `MainActivity.java`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        hideBars();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        hideBars();
    }
    void hideBars(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }
```

How can I get the two bars to go away permanently without immediately reappearing when I tap?

Comment: Have you tried <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> and then just overriding the colours?

Comment: Are you trying to build a fullscreen app or just wanting to hide status and navigation bar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kiosk mode in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

NoActionBar should solve your problem.

```
<style name=“AppTheme” parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix the issue of the action bar reappearing every time I tap within the app window.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out what was wrong. In order to prevent the bars from reappearing after tapping, the `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE` flag has to be set. This makes it so that the action bar only reappears when users swipe from the edges of the screen.